# Is "Proper English" a Classist Construct?

Tags: english

In a [recent item](https://www.goodreads.com/author_blog_posts/6315752-sorry-absinthe-you-re-much-too-slow?ref=ru_lihp_up_abp_4_mclk&uid=6315752) largely addressing using dialect in writing, author Elizabeth Bear asserted the following:

> ...standard or "proper" English is a social construct intended as a
>   measure of class control and segregation. It doesn't exist as a real,
>   unconstructed thing. The linguist's viewpoint is that "correct"
>   language is any language as spoken by a fluent native speaker. The
>   end.

I'm a little fascinated by the suggestion that "proper English" is directly related to class discrimination, but I haven't been able to find much to support the idea via Google (mostly I get guides to proper English).

I've certainly seen some of this anecdotally: I have acquaintances that have directly asserted the people that mispronounce certain words (particularly "nuclear" as "nuke-you-ler" or "ask" as "axe") are less intelligent than people that pronounce such words correctly.

Is Ms. Bear's assertion correct? From a linguistic/anthropological perspective, is the insistence on proper English widely considered to be driven by the desire to discriminate or segregate?

Comment: I'm going to jump in right away and say that I'm not sure this question is appropriate for this Exchange. It seems a better fit than at English Language & Usage, but it still stands out as a bit of an oddball compared to the other questions being asked. Also, I had a harm time finding appropriate tags. Please feel free to suggest better ones...

Comment: I suggest we not use tags at all; they proliferate like cockroaches and serve very little purpose. As for Ms. Bear's remarks, she's absolutely dead-on correct. And where else would "propriety" ever come from, but those who themselves act properly? Look up "ingroup language" and "outgroup language"

Comment: @jlawler: I suggeest that you take your suggestion to Meta Stack Exchange or at least Meta Linguistics. Such complaints proliferate like cockroaches and serve very little purpose. Ooh look how much fun and widely applicable subjective opinions can be (-: But total accord from me as for the objective bit about ingroup / outgroup.

Comment: Highly recommend: David Crystal, "The fight for English" or Lynda Mugglestone "Talking proper."